# PostgreSQL: How to add Column from other table in select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select a column from another table like I used to do in **MSSQL**:

```
 select * , Date = (select top 1 Date from [dbo].TableB where status = 1 order by Date desc)
 from [dbo].TableA
```

**How can I do that in PostgreSQL?**

Additional sample data:

> TableA

```
Names

Richards
Marcos
Luke
Matthew
John
```

> TableB

```
Date        Status
2016-01-01  1
2016-01-02  0
2016-01-03  1
2016-01-04  1
2016-01-05  1
```

Expected Output:

```
Name        Date
Richards    2016-01-02
Marcos      2016-01-02
Luke        2016-01-02
Matthew     2016-01-02
John        2016-01-02
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would `select * , (select NewColumn from [dbo].TableB) as NewColumn` not work?

Comment: Can you please post sample data and expected results?  Do you only have a single record in `tableb`?  If not, it will return multiple results and cause an error most likely...

Comment: @sgeddes-  already edit my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes, it doesn't work ing postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date = (...)` is invalid (standard) SQL and won't work in Postgres (or any other DBMS except for SQL Server)

A column alias is defined using `AS ...` in SQL (and Postgres). Postgres also doesn't have `top`. It uses `limit`.

Using square brackets in an identifier is also not allowed in SQL. So `[dbo]` needs to become `dbo` or `"dbo"` [depending on how you created the schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

```
select a.*, 
       (select date
        from dbo.tableb as b
        where b.status = 1 
        order by b.date desc
        limit 1) as date
from dbo.tablea a
```

`date` is a reserved word and should not be used as an identifier (column name)

If you want to use standard ANSI SQL, you can also use `fetch first 1 row only` instead of `limit 1`.

Another option would be to use `max()` instead of the limit in the sub-select which doesn't need the limit at all:

```
select a.*, 
       (select max(date)
        from dbo.tableb as b
        where b.status = 1) as date
from dbo.tablea a
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax, but did you try this:

```
select * , (select NewColumn from [dbo].TableB) as NewColumn 
 from [dbo].TableA
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Not possible in postgreSQL. :(

Comment: If tableb has more then one row, this won't work. Neither in SQL Server nor in Postgres (where `[dbo].` is an invalid identifier anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.*, b.column
from tableA as a, tableB as b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with PostgreSQL but SQL is still SQL.
First thing to say is you have to have only one result on the second table query and you can do it in

```
 SELECT 
        A.*
        (select NewColumn from [dbo].TableB.NewColumn) as NewColumn 
FROM TableA
```

However I think you'll need to declare a join condition.

```
 SELECT 
        A.*
        (select NewColumn from [dbo].TableB.NewColumn where A.Col1 = TableB.col1)
FROM TableA A
```

without a real example I cant be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.TableA),
    (SELECT Date FROM dbo.TableB WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1)
```